# MySql row to be sorted for performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a MySQL server that keeps events in DB, the DB looks like this:

```
id | epoch_time | type | event_text  | ....
---|------------|------|-------------|-----
01 | 1487671205 | 0    | user-login  | ....
02 | 1487671284 | 0    | user-logout | ....
03 | 1487671356 | 1    | sys_error   | ....
04 | 1487671379 | 0    | user-logout | ....
05 | 1487671389 | 2    | user_error  | ....
06 | 1487671397 | 1    | sys_error   | ....
```

On the web UI, there is a summery of the last 24 hours events by type, since the DB is keeping 1 year back log of data, there are over 1M records at the moment which makes the site loads very slow (from the obvious reasons).

The SQL query is simple,

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM `eventLog` WHERE `epoch_time` >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400)
```

My question is - Is there a way to to "tell" MySQL that the epoch_time column is sorted so that once it hits a raw that has:

```
epoch_time < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400)
```

The query will end.

Thanks

[UPDATE]

Thank you all for your help, I tried to add the index but the performance is still bad (~ 7 - 12 sec' to load the page)

Does it make sense to just keep statistical information just for that ?

Comment: instead of counting ids .. can you try $q->num_rows() . because count(id) put another function to run and hence increase the load of the query.

Comment: Add index on epoch_time, that might help. You could also cache queries. I don't think you show all the 1M results probably just the most recent ones? That's an excellent job for query cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can set epoch_time as index using:

```
ALTER TABLE `eventLog` ADD INDEX epoch_time (`epoch_time`)
```

That will make your query runs much faster,